# Navigation between Angular SPAs using Angular Router

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have to build multiple Angular SPAs for every product type. I will have a common angular app and from this app I have a link called Product Type.

When users clicks on this link, I have to navigate to the appropriate SPA created for that product. I do not want to use server backend to implement this redirection

Each SPA will be running in its own port.
The REST server backend will be running in a completely different server.

Please advice if there is any option to implement this using client side routing?

In the example below, the url redirection should happen inside ProductTypeComponent

Eg: My routes file

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'callback', component: CallbackComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuardService ] 
},
{path: 'productType', component: ProductTypeComponent, canActivate: [ 
AuthGuardService ]},
{ path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Client-side routing is made for in-app navigation. You cannot use it to navigate to a differnt SPA.

Use a simple anchor tag with a `href` property to link to a separate app.

Comment: I want to redirect to different SPA applications from the common app (common app runs in localhost port 3000) based on certain conditions. I tried using router.navigateByUrl() from common app and provided the complete path of SPA app1 (SPA app1 runs in localhost 4200) but it did not work router.navigateByUrl("http://localhost:4200/spa1/");